# Is it possible to have multiple many-to-many relationships between the same two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a few tables that need to be joined together multiple times but I'm not sure if there can be multiple join tables for the same two tables. The tables i have are as follows:

| User | Group | Record |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id PK | Id PK | Id PK |  |
| Name | Name | Name |  |
| etc | etc | Date |  |
|  |  | GroupID FK | //A record can only belong to 1 group |
|  |  | UserID FK | //A record can only have 1 creator/admin |

I then want to have two join tables that can keep track of which group a user is a member of, and which member is an admin of the group.

| Group Members | Group Admins |
| --- | --- |
| GroupID | GroupID |
| UserID | UserID |

A Group can have many members while a user can be a member of many groups.
A Group can have many admins while a user can be an admin of many groups.

I get an error when trying to create the foreign keys for the "Group Members" and "Group Admins" tables.

SQL Query: "ALTER TABLE `GroupMembers` ADD CONSTRAINT `GroupId` FOREIGN KEY (`GroupId`) REFERENCES `Group`(`Id`);"

SQL Error: "Error creating foreign key on GroupId (check data types)"

Is this possible or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why not add a `tinyint(1)` to the GroupMembers join table to keep track of whether the user is an admin or not?

Comment: Yes it's absolutely possible that there are more than one table linking the same two tables. In this particular case it might be tricky though to ensure that a user has to be a member of a group when they are an admin of that group. If that's a requirement, it might be easier to have just one table and another column that flags if the user is an admin or not. "I get an error when trying to create the foreign keys" -- if you need help on that [edit] the question and post a [example], i.e. code that we can run and that produces the error. Also post the exact, verbatim error message.

Comment: @EsliStavenga I like that I dea, thank you.

Comment: @stickybit I've updated the question with the query and error.

Comment: That's not enough. The `CREATE` statements of the tables are required too.

Comment: @stickybit While updating the question, I found that there were restrictions being placed on the foreign keys by my workbench which was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

While updating the question, I found that there were restrictions being placed on the foreign keys by my workbench which was causing the error. The solution was to remove the "on delete" and "on update" restrictions.